# How to use Pretrained Hugging face all-MiniLM-L6-v2 mode using java Deep Java Library

Tags: huggingface-transformers, djl

How to use Pretrained Hugging face all-MiniLM-L6-v2 mode using java. Was able to load the model but facing issues when predicting.Tried writing a custom translator with String input and float output but didnt work .Any examples with Translator would help.

Comment: Can you share your code, please? I only know some Java but might be able to help with a starting project/code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DJL's built-in `TextEmbeddingTranslatorFactory`:

```
String text = "This is an example sentence";

Criteria<String, float[]> criteria = Criteria.builder()
        .setTypes(String.class, float[].class)
        .optModelUrls("djl://ai.djl.huggingface.pytorch/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
        .optEngine("PyTorch")
        .optTranslatorFactory(new TextEmbeddingTranslatorFactory())
        .build();

try (ZooModel<String, float[]> model = criteria.loadModel();
        Predictor<String, float[]> predictor = model.newPredictor()) {
     float[] res = predictor.predict(text);
     System.out.println("Embedding: " + Arrays.toString(res));
}
```

See [djl-demo](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl-demo/tree/master/huggingface/nlp/src/main/java/com/examples) for more huggingface examples.

Comment: Is there any way we could download the model locally and achieve the same

Comment: Yes, you can trace the model into TorchScript model and load the model for local folder.
Use can use the following code convert huggingface model: https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/extensions/tokenizers/src/main/python/model_zoo_importer.py

Once you converted the model (you will get a .zip file), then you can load the model: `.optModelPath(Paths.get("mymodel.zip"))`